# Error installing llvm and clang from source in Linux

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I am trying to  install `clang` from source following the instructions as given in http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html ( Steps 1-4 and 7) in Ubuntu 14.04

Inside the build directory , I ran `make` which succeeded. I wasn't sure what to do after that , so I ran `make install` inside the `build` directory, following which I got this `cmake` error:

[image]

There is no executable named `clang` in `/build/bin` folder anyway, but I can find others like `clang-check`, `clang-query`, etc. What's going wrong?

PS: My main requirment is to experiment with alpha security checkers of `clang` analyzer and also write my own checker later.

Comment: have you checked out clang into tools folder before doing make?

Comment: Yeah I did. As i said , the /build/bin directory has executables like clang-check, clang-format. This means clang has been installed right? It also has an empty file named clang-3.9 . But , there isn't any 'clang' executable